# Is my web site structured correctly?

Tags: c#, javascript, beginner, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a better handle of code organization and how HTML5 (really HTML) stack works in general. I've worked mostly with ASP.NET Webforms and done some MVC as well. Let me say now, "I hate magic". I hate figuring out the magic. I just want it to work in the manner that it's supposed to. So I posted this little HTML5 site on GitHub. Nothing fancy. At all. The structure is very MVC like and I do as much separation of files and code-behind as possible.

All I'm using is: HTML, JavaScript, jQuery, no CSS, and CSHTML (as codebehind).

So in short, is this good? Is this bad? What could be better?

[Code on Github](https://github.com/gamebeta2003/HTML5TestSite)

Mainpage.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Mainpage
/// </summary>
///
namespace Models
{
    public class Mainpage
    {
        private SqlConnection sqlConn;
        private string connStr;

        public Mainpage()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        private void sqlInit()
        {
            connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestInput"].ConnectionString;
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        }

        public Mainpage(int id, string ld, DateTime? dm, string op1, string op2)
        {
            ID = id;
            LineDesc = ld;
            DateMade = dm;
            Options1 = op1;
            Options2 = op2;
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string LineDesc { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateMade { get; set; }
        public string Options1 { get; set; }
        public string Options2 { get; set; }

        public void Save()
        {
            sqlInit();
            string insertStr = "usr_InsertValues";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(insertStr, sqlConn);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter sp;
            if (DateMade.HasValue)
                sp = new SqlParameter("@p2", DateMade.Value);
            else
                sp = new SqlParameter("@p2", DBNull.Value);

            SqlParameter[] sps = new SqlParameter[] {new SqlParameter("@p1", LineDesc),
                                                     sp,
                                                     new SqlParameter("@p3", Options1),
                                                     new SqlParameter("@p4", Options2)};
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(sps);

            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Default.cs (ViewModel)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Default
/// </summary>
///
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class Default
    {

        public Default()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        public Default(string desc, string sop1, string sop2, string sop3)
        {
            Description = desc;
            SelectedOp1 = sop1;
            SelectedOp2 = sop2;
            SelectedOp3 = sop3;
        }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string SelectedOp1 { get; set; }
        public string SelectedOp2 { get; set; }
        public string SelectedOp3 { get; set; }
        public List<string> Option1 { get; set; }
        public List<string> Option2 { get; set; }
        public List<string> Option3 { get; set; }

        public void Save()
        {
            Models.Mainpage mp = new Models.Mainpage(0, Description, new DateTime?(DateTime.Now), SelectedOp1, SelectedOp2);
            mp.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Default.cshtml (Controller/Code behind)

```
@{
    var linedesc = Request.Form["linedesc"];
    var datemade = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    var food = Request.Form["options1"];
    var drinks = Request.Form["options2"];

    string[] data = new String[4] {linedesc, datemade, food, drinks};

    // Go back to Default.html and keep values selected, ie. values don't reset
    var blah = "hi";

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    if (IsPost)
    {
        ViewModels.Default vm = new ViewModels.Default(linedesc, food, drinks, null);
        vm.Save();
    }
    Json.Write(data, Response.Output);

}
```

Default.html (View)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Testing Stuff</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Views/JS/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Views/JS/Default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainpage" method="post" action="../Controllers/Default">
        <div style="clear:both;" id="dbInput">
            <label for="linedesc">Description:</label>&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="linedesc" name="linedesc" />

            <br /><br />

            <input id="fruits" name="options1" value="fruits" type="radio" />
            <label for="fruits">Fruits</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="candies" name="options1" value="candies" type="radio" />
            <label for="candies">Candies</label>&nbsp;
            <input id="snacks" name="options1" value="snacks" type="radio" />
            <label for="snacks">Snacks</label>

            <br /><br />

            <label for="options2">Choose beverage:</label>&nbsp;
             <select id="options2" name="options2">
                <option value="Coca-Cola">Coca-Cola</option>
                <option value="Sprite">Sprite</option>
                <option value="Root Beer">Root Beer</option>
                <option value="Orange Juice">Orange Juice</option>
            </select>

            <br /><br />

            <label for="options3">Sample:</label>&nbsp;
            <select id="options3" name="options3">

            </select>

            <input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Default.js (JavaScript)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#submitText').click(function () {
    // $('#txtHolder').html('<span>I am like code behind in txtHolder.</span>');
    // $('#results').html('<span>Results are here today.</span>');
    //});

    $('#mainpage').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hi");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        var frm = $(e.target);
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../Controllers/Default.cshtml",
            data: formData,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                var options3 = $("#options3");
                options3.empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
                {
                    options3.append(
                        $("<option></option>").text(response[i]).val(response[i])
                    );
                }
                // Adds data to dropdown
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Sorry, there seems to be a problem contacting the server.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

On the HTML side, don't use `<br/>` to force the content to a new line. Place contents in `<div>` instead.

```
<div>
  <label for="linedesc">Description:</label>&nbsp;
  ...
</div>
<div>
  <input id="fruits" name="options1" value="fruits" type="radio" />
  ...
</div>
<div>
  <label for="options2">Choose beverage:</label>&nbsp;
  ...
</div>
<div>
  <label for="options3">Sample:</label>&nbsp;
  ...
</div>
```

On the JS side of things, load scripts last to avoid blocking the UI. It's better if the user can see the page first while scripts load, rather than a blank page because scripts load. Place them before `</body>` preferrably.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Views/JS/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Views/JS/Default.js"></script>
</body>
```

And some script improvements:

```
// A function to a jQuery function is shorthand for $(document).ready(fn);
$(function () {

  // I highly guess this is a static container. I'd cache it
  // in a variable to avoid jQuery fetching it again every submit.
  var options3 = $("#options3");

  //Commented out code is useless code. Get rid of it.

  $('#mainpage').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // And unless you have reason for the alert, don't use it.
    // In debugging, console.log() is better, and breakpoints are even better than both

    //e.target and "this" in this handler is the same
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();

    // You can use the form action attribute for the url. Don't hardcode. 
    // If it's different, you can store it in a data-* variable
    // Use data-* variables for dynamic stuff generated on page.
    // Helps you get along with backend devs who generate the HTML but hate writing JS (or mixing code with it);
    var url = form.attr('action'); //form.data('action') if it was in data-action="URL" in the HTML

    // Shorthand AJAX post. Nulled the third since we use promises.
    $.post(url, formData, null, 'json')
      .done(function (response) {
        options3.empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          // jQuery also accepts self-closing tags to create elements.
          // Also, there's an appendTo() function, which looks much cleaner in this case
          $('<option/>').text(response[i]).val(response[i]).appendTo(option3);
        }
        // Adds data to dropdown
      }).fail(function () {
        // In this case, it's a warning. I'll let the alert through.
        // There are things called "modals" too, much prettier than alerts. Just sayin' :D
        alert("Sorry, there seems to be a problem contacting the server.");
      });
  });
});
```

Then I'm no expert in C# and the backing data store, but it's better if on the values of your choices, you used the ID's of the choices rather than the text. Scenario: What if someone modified the data to have 2 or more "Coca-Cola" entries. How would you know which is which?

But, if you had a unique id for each item, then you'd know which one regardless if you named them the same. In the real world, that's how you differentiate 2 or more people of the same name on Facebook (or any site for that  matter) - the user id.

```
// In the HTML
<select>
  <option value="1">Coke</option>
  <option value="2">Pepsi</option>
  <option value="3">Coke</option>
  <option value="4">Dr. Pepper</option>
</select>

// In your data storage, something like:
[
  {"id":1,"text":"Coke"},        <-- This is a different coke
  {"id":2,"text":"Pepsi"},
  {"id":3,"text":"Coke"},        <-- This is also a different coke
  {"id":4,"text":"Dr. Pepper"}
]
```

I'll leave the C# to the other guys here.

Comment: 1 - Doesn't .ready already handle having the script load after the page loads? 2 - I didn't quite understand what you meant by the ID suggestion? Aren't I already doing that?

Comment: @dotnetN00b 1. I'm not talking about when the script executes. I'm talking about when the script loads (from the server). If your scripts are on the `<head>` and took too long to load (from the server), all you get is a blank white page. Placing them to the bottom makes the page render first, and have it block loading somewhere later.

Comment: @dotnetN00b As for ID, something like `<option value="1">Coca-Cola</option>`

Comment: Also, even if I use divs to cause a newline effect, I'd still need another <br /> to have the content have actual space between them. Or is there another way to do that? In short, is there a way to replace "<br /><br />"?

Comment: @dotnetN00b Use margins or paddings to add some space between them.

Answer (score 3):

For the JavaScript,

- Drop the commented out code
- Avoid alert, it is very annoying
- You do not use `frm`, drop it
- You can merge the assignment of `options3` and `empty` into one line
- `options3` is a terrible name, both for an `id` as a variable name

Other than, that code looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

Razor is a ***view engine.*** It's completely abusive to try to use it as a "controller" as you've done here. If you want a code behind, then Aspx & webforms is the correct architecture to use.

But that suffers from the same issues as the abuse of razor you've done here. Tightly coupled view/business logic. It's evil. *Evil.* Don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

One small point on the c# side.  As SqlConnection implements `IDisposable` I would rather consider wrapping that in using statement within the Save method.  This way if a problem occurs in the `ExecuteNonQuery` method you can ensure the SqlConnection is closed and you don't incur any leaks.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
}
```

In saying that I might also consider passing in the SqlConnection to the model class.  This way you take away the responsibility of the Model from knowing how to create this aspect.

To do this, you might consider using an interface for your model which takes a connection.

```
interface IPersistable
{
    void Save(SqlConnection connection);
}

public class ModelContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestInput"].ConnectionString;

    public void Save(IPersistable model)
    {
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            model.Save(connection);
        }
    }
}

public class Mainpage : IPersistable 
{
    public void Save(SqlConnection connection)
    {
            string insertStr = "usr_InsertValues";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(insertStr, sqlConn);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter sp;
            if (DateMade.HasValue)
                sp = new SqlParameter("@p2", DateMade.Value);
            else
                sp = new SqlParameter("@p2", DBNull.Value);

            SqlParameter[] sps = new SqlParameter[] {new SqlParameter("@p1", LineDesc),
                                                     sp,
                                                     new SqlParameter("@p3", Options1),
                                                     new SqlParameter("@p4", Options2)};
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(sps);

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
}
```

**ViewModel.Save()**

I'm not a huge fan of having the viewmodel responsible for calling the model to persist the data.  I'm not sure where you could move this to as I haven't looked at the rest of the code but I would typically put that call in the controller and use a mapping layer to copy the properties from ViewModel to model.

My main reason is that it seems to violate the boundary between the viewmodel and model in that now viewmodels know about models.  I tend to prefer the level of dependency direction going toward a ViewModel not away from it i.e. *View => ViewModel, Controller => ViewModel*

Comment: So I would create a Model, take the data from ViewModel and put in Model, pass that Model to ModelContext, and finally call all of that from the Controller (or what I have as the Controller). Correct?

Comment: @dotnetN00b yep, spot on.  So the controller is controlling everything and pulling the strings (so to speak) and the actual implementations are doing very specific work.